# Windows batch create log file, but do not want space at the end

Tags: windows, batch-file

I create log file with batch script

```
set mydate=H^|%date:~-7,2%/%date:~-10,2%/%date:~-4,4%^|0
echo %mydate:|=^|% >log.txt
set tadate=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%
ren log.txt log%tadate%.txt
```

Result (log20160416.txt):

```
H|16/04/2016|0
```

I have "Space" at the end of line.
I do not want it. Help me please.

Comment: Change `echo %mydate:|=^|% >log.txt` by `>log.txt echo %mydate:|=^|%`

Comment: I have another problem.
The result file has "New line", but I need only "One line".

    H|16/04/2016|0
    

How can I delete blank line, please